# Is it possible attach a widget to the Android background?

Tags: android, widget

I was wondering if is it possible attach a widget to the main Android background/wallpaper/desktop?

I want develop something like a clock, actually It's a very simple widget that have three buttons. This is quite different from another desktop-widgets-like, all the widgets that I've seen are like a customization of the Android wallpaper, or a customization of the Android unlocker, but this is rather different.

If it is possible, do you know some sample code source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what "background/wallpaper/desktop" really means, as "background" is too wide term, "wallpaper" may be either static bitmap or **live wallpaper**, "desktop" means nothing on Android (did you mean Launcher by any odd chance?). If you meant live wallpaper, then you cannot have full functionality in Live Wallpaper you have on Launcher, but if "three buttons" means you want to allow user to tap certain area and react on this, then it should be not a big problem - you can use `onTouchEvent()` to receive taps from user and act accordingly. If you meant Launcher then well, "yes". For any other options "no" or "most likely no"

Comment: Hello, and thanks for reply. Just a moment ago I found my answer right here [link](http://buildmobile.com/how-to-code-an-android-widget/). This guy made something like a clock, but I think that I can advance over this code.